# Set encoding in ballerina.io for HTTP GET response (ISO-8859-1 )

Tags: ballerina, ballerina-http

I download several CSV files via HTTP endpoints and write them into a database.  This works.
But I noticed that parts of my response are wrongly encoded.

Example:

```
var response = endpoint->get("url");
io:println(response.getTextPayload().toString());
```

looks like this:

```
ZYR;ZYR;;Br�sse;Br�ssel;Br�ssel Railway;S;N;N;BE
ZYZ;ZYZ;;Brussl;Br�ssel;Br�ssel Railway;S;N;N;BE
```

The following letters are wrongly encoded äöüÄÖÜ (German letters).

Is it possible to set the correct encoding for the response. For example in ISO-8859-1?

Many greetings,
Martin

Answer (score 1):

The getXXXPayload() functions use the `charset` given in the `Content-type` response header for the payload encoding.

```
Content-Type: [text/html; charset=utf-8]
```

Please check the `Content-type` response header, whether it contains the required charset or not.

Comment: Many thanks for the answer.

Unfortunately the server does not set a charset. When I execute the following command:

log:printInfo("getContentType: "+ response.getHeader("Content-Type"));
I get the following output:

text/x-comma-separated-values
Are there other ways to set the encoding?

Answer (score 0):

Oh, my bad. Of course I can set the content-type afterwards.

```
response.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/x-comma-separated-values; charset=ISO-8859-1");
```